# self-join mysql table

Tags: mysql, join

**payday**

```
  id   day    employee    income    expenses    tax
   1    7        3         600        100       30
   2    14       3         650        150       35
   3    14       2         680        200       38


SELECT p.income, p.tax, ps.expenses
FROM paydays p
LEFT JOIN paydays ps ON ps.day+7 = p.day
WHERE p.day = 14 AND p.employee = 3
```

this gives what i want, 650 income and 35 tax from row with day 14,
and 100 expenses from row with day 7

now the problem,

```
SELECT SUM(p.income), SUM(p.tax), SUM(ps.expenses)
FROM paydays p
LEFT JOIN paydays ps ON ps.day+7 = p.day
WHERE p.day = 14
```

it should give

```
income = 1330  
tax = 73  
expenses = 100
```

but it multiplies fields by 2, `income = 2660, tax = 146.....`

Comment: how can expances be 100?

Comment: Just wondering why did you leave the employee join in your query. If I put the employee join it gives me income = 1330  
tax = 73  
expenses = 100

Comment: i don't care about the employees in second query, just totals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something in your explanation but can't you use a subquery to get the `expenses`, similar to this:

```
SELECT SUM(p.income) TotalIncome, 
  SUM(p.tax) TotalTax, 
  ps.expenses Expenses
FROM paydays p
INNER JOIN
(
  select sum(expenses) expenses, day
  from paydays
  where day = 7
  group by day
) ps 
  ON ps.day+7 = p.day
WHERE p.day = 14
GROUP BY ps.expenses
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e4b9/12)

The result is:

```
| TOTALINCOME | TOTALTAX | EXPENSES |
-------------------------------------
|        1330 |       73 |      100 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(payday.income) as Income , 
    SUM(payday.tax) as Tax,  
    p.expenses as Expanses
FROM payday
LEFT JOIN payday as p ON p.id = payday.id - 1
WHERE day = 14
```

Comment: no, i want the expenses from the previous row, so if day = 14, i want expenses from day-7

Comment: but you did not explain in your question

Comment: See the edited question and always clearly tell us what you really want

Comment: what the.... why did you downvoted that? i haven't and won't edit my question, if your mind doesn't get it you can always **** off